# Visual Studio Tools for Docker - PrepareForCompile task failed unexpectedly

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I took a clean machine (Windows 10 Enterprise w/out the Anniversary Update) and installed (in this order) Full IIS, Hyper-V, VS2015 Enterprise, .NET Core 1.0.1 Tooling Preview 2, Docker for Windows, Visual Studio Docker Tools, and a few other random programs.

I then opened VS2015 and created a default .NET core website.  When I run (F5) all works as expected.  I then right clicked on the project and went to `Add->Docker Support`.  Now when trying to run (F5) using Docker I see this error message:

> MSB4018 The "PrepareForCompile" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandlineClientException: Error response
>   from daemon: Container ... is not running at ...

I have searched online and the only thing I can find that might explain it is that I don't think Shared Drives are working.  I did set it up in Docker->Shared Drives, but when I run: 
`docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data`
the response is empty.

Likewise when I try using busy box the directory is empty.

`docker run -it -v /C/Users:/wormhole busybox
cd wormhole
ls`

I have tried using **Windows Desktop for Docker** 1.12.1-stable and beta 26. Both have the same issue.

Some have indicated that Antivirus could cause a problem.  I do have Mcafee installed, but I cannot uninstall or disable the antivirus software.

Some have suggested that passwords with unusual characters can cause this issue but that does not apply here.

I don't know that shared drives are causing the VS2015 error, but it seems like a good place to start since shared drives are broken.

I have restarted bot hdock and the computer many times, to no avail.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue.

In order to fix it I found the container referenced by the id in the stack trace. Then I removed it:

```
docker rm <containerid>
```

When I tried running from VS 2015 again it worked. I don't know what initially caused the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to add since I also stumbled upon this issue. I had a clean Win 10 machine, and I just had to enable the "Shared Drive" setting in docker:

This may not be the actual problem that you're facing (Thankfully you fixed it!); this is just for people that may not have this enabled!

[image: Step 1: Right Click on Docker Icon in taskbar]

[image: Step 2: Click Settings]

[image: Step 3: Click Shared Drives. Select the Checkbox for your hard drive, and click "Apply"]